# I've narrowed my question down substantially. Should I edit the original or create a new one?

Tags: discussion, edits, questions, etiquette, reposts

I asked a [general question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115104/how-to-create-keybindings-for-a-custom-minor-mode-in-emacs) to which I received some answers that were ok, but not really a solution. I narrowed the problem down to one very specific thing, which is much narrower than the original question. Should I just edit the original, or should I make a new question?

I ask since the answers to the more general question are useful, but only if you haven't yet worked your way to the specific question. So, people wouldn't be searching for the narrow question when they need the information provided in the answers to the original.

(In this case the original question to what would be the narrower is:
'How to create keybindings for a custom minor mode in Emacs' ==> 'How to get the kbd macro to work in a list within a custom minor mode definition in Emacs')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the original question has answers I'd start a new question.

I'd also answer the original question myself with a reference to the new question and up-vote any and all answers that helped. Accept the answer that helped the most, or if you really can't decide accept your own.

Answer (score 2):

Probably better to start afresh (perhaps with a link to the existing question).

If you insist on editing it is imperative that you *leave the original text* so that people who answered the original question don't get down-voted for not answering the clarified version.

Comment: What's a, "t a link"? - a url link?

Comment: @Peter: a typo...I meant "a link", which is to say use the little "world" icon in the editor to create a hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that there was some secret hidden link type... kind of like the secret menu at In-N-Out.